# How to get string

Tags: c#, split

I have a string like:

```
"S=35 , P=232 , a=12"
```

I want to just keep the string which is between `"S="` and `","` and `"P="` - `","` `"a="`,`","`. How can I do that? Must I use a Regex or can I do it in another way?

Comment: Investigate String.Split, once on , then on =

Comment: String St = "S=35 , P=232 , a=12";

int pFrom = St.IndexOf("S=") + "S=".Length;
int pTo = St.LastIndexOf(",");

String result = St.Substring(pFrom, pTo - pFrom);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could instantiate a stringbuilder and then load the string into a character array. Do a For Each Loop to iterate through each character in the array.  If the character is not numeric, add it to the stringbuilder.  If it is skip to the next character.  Once done just do Stringbuilder.ToString().

Answer (score 1):

You can try *Linq* and convert the string into a dictionary:

```
 string source = "S=35 , P=232 , a=12";

 Dictionary<string, string> dict = source
   .Split(',')
   .Select(line => line.Split('='))
   .ToDictionary(items => items[0].Trim(), items => items[1].Trim());
```

Having created `dict` you can easily query it:

```
 string p = dict["P"];

 if (dict.TryGetValue("a", out var a)) {
   // "a" exists, its value in a
 }
```

If you want to get digits only, i.e. obtain `"3523212"` you can try another Linq:

```
 string result = string.Concat(source.Where(c => c >= '0' && c <= '9'));
```

You don't have to use *regular expressions*, but you can easily do it:

```
 // "35 232 12"
 string matches = string.Join(" ", Regex
   .Matches(source, "[0-9]+")
   .Cast<Match>()
   .Select(match => match.Value));
```